# What laws are void when one goes out of their way to do something?

Tags: criminal-law

I want to ask for various examples where something is typically legal, but becomes illegal when someone forces or manipulates a situation as a loophole around the law. For example, if someone from a state with an age of consent at 18 crosses state borders to have sex with a minor because their states age of consent is 16, in this case we'd call that sex tourism.

Are there other such examples? I'm particularly interested in the Kenosha shooting situation because it's very clear the teenager crossed state borders to antagonize protesters solely to force a self-defense situation. Is forcing or manipulating a situation just to have an excuse to use lethal force against the law?

Comment: FWIW, there is not a law of the specific type you describe. The broader question takes more thought and I'll answer if I can think of any examples.

Comment: Under federal law, it is legal to cross state lines to have sex with anyone *over 16,* not over 18. (The relevant statute has a convoluted path to the definition of "age of consent"; 42 USC § 2423 (b) sends you to (f)(1), which in turn sends you to 18 USC § 2243 (a).) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ages_of_consent_in_the_United_States#Federal_laws

Comment: @Justaguy You are absolutely insane to think that's legal. Your own source says "{Chapter 117, 18 U.S.C. 2423(b)} forbids traveling in interstate or foreign commerce to engage in "illicit sexual conduct" with a minor; this is considered one form of sexual tourism. 2423(f) refers to Chapter 109A as its bright line for defining "illicit sexual conduct" as far as non-commercial sexual activity is concerned."

Comment: @Lex_i  Just **two sentences** after the bit you quote, Wikipedia says that under Chapter 109A, the age of consent is "12 years if one is within 4 years of the 12-to-15-year-old's age, **16 under all other circumstances.**"

Comment: @Justaguy I never specified the age of the perpetrator, so you weren't correcting anything. A person may still be guilty of sex tourism even if a minor goes to a state that has a different gap.

Comment: @Lex_i I obviously misunderstood you. My apologies.

Comment: @Justaguy its alright, sorry for my hostility

Comment: In the case of Rittenhouse, he was in WI for his job as a lifeguard. The property owner asked for assistance. The gun was borrowed. Seems a lot like Rittenhouse was the victim of three violent convicted felons (one was a child rapist, another was a 10x felon & abuser) and acted in self defense.

Comment: @acpilot, actually I did a lot of research since the post. The alleged child rapist is actually being defamed. In both Wisconsin's and Arizona's database and registry nothing shows up about him having any child sex offenses. The other was indeed guilty of domestic violence in Arizona.

Also: the property owner cannot ask for assistance unless the actor providing assistance is immediate family, officially employed by the merchant, etc.

Comment: @acpilot Also, Wisconsin's penal code in 939.49 and 939.49(2) and (b) show that self-defense is not a right, but a privilege. One must follow the conditions outlined in the statutes to claim self-defense, conditions that which Kyle failed to satisfy. I already mentioned he did not have legal authority to protect third person property, but two big issues is that his fears of death were speculative rather than imminent and his conduct was provocative. Kyle even fails to satisfy conditions felons must abide to claim self defense via guns according to State v. Edwards in 2015.

Comment: @Lex_i I read the same statutes and can't understand how you arrive at your conclusion, other than you want Kyle to be wrong. This is pretty clear cut.  Kyle had to defend himself from multiple violent attackers who were going to hurt or kill him.  He did so with care and only took action against specific attackers when and to the extent necessary.  The videos show everything in gorey detail and from multiple angles.

Comment: @acpilot, it's pretty obvious. He wants to claim he had an imminent/impending fear of death, but all his threats of death were speculative. A thrown coke bottle, plastic bag, are not lethal. Even the skateboard that struck him wasn't lethal because it struck his back with the grip tape rather than to his vital organs or head with the metal trucks.

Comment: @acpilot He also shot into a crowd at one point. But prior to the shootings witnesses claim on video that he was harassing people. Him and his militia were pointing lasers (with their guns) at people. At that point that is more than harassment, it's threat of lethal force. It's also provocation, which the statutes state clearly removes privilege to claim self-defense EVEN if one responds to lethal force.

Comment: I feel as though this is a political issue (vs. a question of law) for you and I'm sorry you feel this way.  Much of what you said is simply false and, as much as I want to, I'm not going to unpack everything in a comment section.  All I can say is that I believe the video tells the tale and I think the law will reach the same conclusion.  We shall see.

Comment: The video absolutely tells the tale. And this is absolutely an issue of BOTH politics and law. I'm not going to repeat myself the details again; but boiled down Kyle
- Lacked legal authority to defend third person property according to Wisconsin's statutes
- Possessed and open carried a firearm illegally across state borders.
- Joined a militia that was known to be racist and glorify violence on Facebook to the point Facebook had to ban the group.
- Had just beaten a young girl from BEHIND mere weeks prior to the shooting. So he has a history of unprovoked violence.

Comment: - provoked people through harassment with his militia group (therefore cannot claim self-defense)
- and initiated lethal force by first shooting someone in the head and back over a thrown plastic bag. A plastic bag with no weight to it. He also shot into a crowd while running. 

You legitimately must have a personal motive to defend Kyle if you think he had any right using lethal force against people.

Comment: The gun did not cross state lines.  I recognize that you are working with a set of facts that don't necessarily align with mine, and that's fine.  Let's see how it plays out.  Be careful with the "unprovoked violence" character thing.  Remember, each one of his wounded/killed attackers had non-trivial criminal records.  Criminal backgrounds of all involved likely won't be disclosed to the jury if this goes to trial.  And ease off the "-ist" and "-ism."  That unfounded nonsense undermines your credibility.

Comment: How did it not? In order from him to have made it to Kenosha with his rifle, he'd need to have had brought his rifle with him. The gun did not just teleport from antioch illinois. 
Second, only one of his victims had a record (and having a record does not affect the privilege to claim self-defense, especially given that Kyle did not know their criminal records prior to the shooting).

Comment: Lastly, the racism in his militia is not unfounded and does not undermine my credibility whatsoever. Read https://www.theverge.com/2020/8/26/21403004/facebook-kenosha-militia-groups-shooting-blm-protest and not to mention Kyle's very open and public history of supporting Blue Lives Matter, a movement meant solely to counter Black Lives Matter which ends up preserving racist police brutality.

Comment: You seem to have this figured out.  Thank you for your perspective.